# Please Identify these tires and are they ok for truck?

Tags: tires, chevrolet

I have a 86 Chevrolet C30 dually truck.  The tires are something I've never seen before.  The brand is "A ? X" (some symbol in middle).  A mechanic said these may be nylon tires  and could be the cause of my rough ride around 70mph.

What are these tires and why cant I find them online?

[image]

Two (That reads 7.50 - 16)

[image]

Other Details:

Tubeless.  RIM 600G.  10 P.R.E. 
112/116 nylon tread 6 plies sidewall 4 plies 
max load single 2755 pounds at 75 PSI cold 
max load duel 2470 pounds at 75 PSI cold

Comment: When you post the picture include all the specifications, size, weight rating, and any other data that is on the sidewall.

Comment: @mikes - Pics uploaded.  Please let me know if I missed anything, I'm no expert mechanic but I am willing to look at whatever I can to help.

Comment: I found a sticker on the inside of my truck door that said Tires 40PSI.  I think this means the tires should be inflated to 40PSI on this truck.  Right now the front are 33psi and rear are 25psi.  I think that explains the sink.  I'll air them up and see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tires are made in China and may have been a house brand or low cost replacement no-name tire. The first picture shows a tire that appears to be under inflated or over loaded. I was unable to see in the photos what type of construction the tire has. It should say somewhere on the sidewall 6ply rayon or 8ply steel etc.  Back in the day when nylon or fiberglass belts were common many people complained of flat spots or tread shimmy. It was more pronounced on tires that sat for extended periods or even a short time underinflated. In some cases it improved as the tire warmed up, in other it did not. You also want to make sure that the tires are rated for your truck. One-tons came in variety of gross vehicle weights. I personally wouldn't be doing 70mph on a tire of unknown age and quality. Typically the tires would also have an LT designation for light truck. After a little research they are made by The Shifeng Juxing Tire Co. The good news is they have only been in business since 2003, so they can't be more than 10 years old. They were most likely imported by the container full and wholesaled to independents.

Comment: The side says nylon tread 6 plies, sidewall 4 plies.

Comment: Although they appear to be DOT (Dept. of Transportation) approved I am concerned about the lack of Light Truck designation. It may be that they are only trailer rated but there is no way to tell.

Comment: On the inside of the tire the DOT # is more complete, ending in 5109.  According to my research this means the tire was born in the 51st week of 2009.